# The space of bounded operators $L(X \rightarrow X)$ where $X=\ell_1$ is NOT seperable

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, separable-spaces

How can one prove that the space of bounded operators $L(X \rightarrow X)$ where $X=\ell_1$ is NOT seperable? I am trying to think what can contradict seperability, but I didn't have any progress.

Comment: Do you know why $\ell_\infty \cong \ell_1^*$ is not separable? Can you see that we can choose a vector in $\ell_1$ and build an embedding of $\ell_\infty$ in $L(\ell_1)$?

Comment: The "standard" way to demonstrate a normed vector source is not separable is to give an uncountable subset, all of whose elements are pairwise the same fixed distance apart. I'm not sure it applies here, but it's a good first place to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the canonical Schrauder Basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ given by $e_n(k)=\delta_{kn}$. Each permutation $\sigma: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ induces an isometric linear map $T_\sigma: X \rightarrow X$ given by $T_{\sigma}(e_n)=e_{\sigma(n)}$. Now, for two distinct permutations $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ there exists $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sigma_1(k)\neq \sigma_2(k)$. Thus, $$\|T_{\sigma_1}-T_{\sigma_2}\|\geq \|T_{\sigma_1}(e_k)-T_{\sigma_2}(e_k)\|=\|e_{\sigma_1(k)}-e_{\sigma_2(k)}\|=2.$$ Then $\{T_\sigma: \sigma \text{ is a permutation on }\mathbb{N}\}$ is an uncountable subset of $\ell^1(\mathbb{N})$ whose elements are all a distance of at least $2$ apart.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the following. Let $E\subset\mathbb{N}.$ Define
$T_E:X\to X$ by
$$T_E(e_n)=\begin{cases} e_n & n\in E\\
0 & n\notin E\end{cases}$$
where $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ denotes the standard topological basis in $\ell^1.$

Then $\|T_E\|=1$ and $\|T_E-T_F\|=2$ for $E\neq F.$
The cardinality of $\{T_E\}_{E\subset \mathbb{N}}$ is continuum.

According to suggestion of @RobertFurber, one can as well consider
$$S_E(x)=\left (\sum_{n\in E} x_n\right )e_1$$ Again $\|S_E\|=1,$ $\|S_E-S_F\|=2$ for $E\neq F.$

**Remark** The first method can be applied to any $\ell^p$ space.